# XML linear layout vertical

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Below you see my xml: 
    I have a < linearlayout> < relativelayout/> < /linearlayout> hierarchy

The only thing I want is that all the images+text are vertically placed belowed eachother + horizontally centralised on the screen..
    I have tried too much xml to reach this result, but nothing works..

The first problem is that the textswitcher inside the relativelayout places itself next to the imageswitcher in the relativelayout..

the second problem is that imageswitcher + textswitcher after the < /relativelayout> won't appear on the screen... :(

(I need this relativelayout inside the linearlayout because I animate the relativelayout and cannot delete it)

thank you for the help!!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutid"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background_donker" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wolkanim"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@anim/wolkanimation" />



    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutid2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/imageswitchertrein"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out"
        />

        <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/textswitcherafstandtekst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fadenieuw"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/fadenieuwout"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

     </RelativeLayout>


   <ImageSwitcher
     android:id="@+id/imageswitcherspoor"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
     android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out"
     android:src="@drawable/spoor" >
    </ImageSwitcher>

     <TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/textswitcherstationnaam"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fadenieuw"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/fadenieuwout" 
       />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that the `RelativeLayout` is filling the `LinearLayout`, therefore everything in your RL is on top of you LL contents. Also, unlike the `LinearLayout` which pushes the next child either down or to the right, `RelativeLayout` children need defined positioning, such as `android:layout_below="@+id/..."` or margins set.

When I fill the contents of each element in your layout the following code works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_donker"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wolkanim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@anim/wolkanimation" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutid2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >


        <ImageSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/imageswitchertrein"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
            android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out" />

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/textswitcherafstandtekst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageswitchertrein"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:inAnimation="@anim/fadenieuw"
            android:outAnimation="@anim/fadenieuwout"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/imageswitcherspoor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out"
        android:src="@drawable/spoor" >
    </ImageSwitcher>

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/textswitcherstationnaam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fadenieuw"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/fadenieuwout" />

</LinearLayout>
```